# Confusing scope and self invocations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, self-invoking-function

Let's look at this example:

```
var x = 3;

var obj = {
  x:2,
  test: function(){
    var x = 1;
    console.log(this.x);
  } 
};
```

And then we have different ways to call this function:

```
obj.test(); // line 1

obj.test.call(null); // line 2

(obj.test)(); // line 3

(obj.test = obj.test)(); // line 4

(obj.test || obj.test)(); // line 5

(obj.test && obj.test)(); // line 6

(obj.test, obj.test)(); // line 7
```

I understand first 3 lines but can anyone explain me what is going on further ( line 4 to 7 ). That is confusing.

Comment: In short, the 'this' is not bound to the literal scope (of object obj) but is set dynamically. Therefore, .call(context, parameters) or .apply(context, parametersarray) can be used for controlling the context and controlling the 'this' of the function. Using the 'this' the way it is used in your example is not preferred and ambigious. Try to refer to the object explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 4 to 7 in each case it returns the function only, not the context. So when you have grabbed the function from the object, it loses it's context.And then it tries to call the function, the `this` in it refer to the global object, which is the window and `x` in window is 3. So in `use strict` mode it will be null, in other mode it will be the window.

**4)** Assign the right hand value to the left hand value and return it

```
(obj.test = obj.test)()
```

**5)** If the first operand is true, return it, else return the second operand

```
obj.test || obj.test
```

**6)** If the first and second operands are true, return the first operand, else return the second operand

```
obj.test && obj.test
```

**7)** In this case it only returns the second object. `,` comma only separates the object from each other

```
(obj.test, obj.test)()
```

Comment: That has a sens but I can't understand why for this 4 lines function loses its context. Other words why line 4 is different then line 3

Comment: @Przemek line 3 doesn't return anything, but `=` operator works like that.

Comment: JS works like that. if you assign the function from the object, it will get the function, but not the context.

Comment: I mean result in a console. line 3 it is 2 but line 4 console log is 3. When I do  (obj.test = obj.test) and then obj.test() console.log is still 2

Comment: `obj.test = obj.test` will assign and return the value.So it return the function which's context is lost. (obj.test)() returns not the function but the `obj.test`, because in `()` there is no operator